# TFS "always" keep asking me for check-out using visual studio online

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs, enterprise-library, azure-devops

For enterprise library `.edmx` file. When I added new table or modified table it keep asking me for check-out which is already checked-out.

I am using VS Express 2012 , Visual Stuido online (TFS). EL 5.0

Anybody had same issue?

Comment: Do you mean Entity Framework?

Comment: Are you able to use Visual Studio 2013?  You'll be able to take advantage of "local workspaces" which don't require check-outs.

Comment: Solved :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674734/tfs-auto-checkout-before-checkin